# How to add @OneToMany mapping for self entity in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity type called precinct. Now I want to have one single precinct had neighbor precincts, which is a self-mapping. So how should I write the annotation for `Set<Precinct>`?

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Precinct")
public class Precinct {

  @Id
  @Column(name="Id")
  private int id;

  @Annotations required here
  public Set<Precinct> getNeighbors() {
    return neighbors;
  }
  public void setNeighbors(Set<Precinct> neighbors) {
    this.neighbors = neighbors;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Precinct")
public class Precinct {

  @Id
  @Column(name="Id")
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Precinct parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Precinct> neighbors;
}
```

Comment: Hi but this cause an error: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: entity.Precinct.parent in entity.Precinct.neighbors

Comment: Did you define `@ManyToOne private Precinct parent;` as it shown in my code snippet?